# FACEBOOK LIKE (URLs. Serve these resources from a consistent URL)

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I want to fix this issue ... I get the following error or waring in the speed performance

The following resources have identical contents, but are served from different URLs. Serve these resources from a consistent URL to save 1 request(s) and 25.2KiB.

```
http://static.ak.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter.php?version=10
https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter.php?version=10
```

I have tried a number of  with this below and still getting the same warnings

js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1";

js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1";

js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1";

Answer (score 1):

This is an action of the Content delivery network used by Facebook.  They decide where to serve you the content from.  You have no control over where it comes from.

If you REALLY want to maintain a constant URL to a certain resource, you might want to try serving that file locally.  Download it to your server and manually specify the URL.

Comment: function __c() {__d("UrlMapConfig",[],{"www":"www.facebook.com","m":"m.facebook.com","connect":"connect.facebook.net","api_https":"api.facebook.com","api_read_https":"api-read.facebook.com","graph_https":"graph.facebook.com","fbcdn_http":"s-static.ak.fbcdn.net","fbcdn_https":"s-static.ak.fbcdn.net","cdn_http":"static.ak.facebook.com","cdn_https":"s-static.ak.facebook.com"});__d("SDKConfig",[],{"xfbmlUseLegacy":true,"migrate":true,"errorHandling":{"rate":2},"api":{"mode":"warn","whitelist":

Comment: When you specify `js.src` for the `all.js` file, just point it to the file you saved on your server.

Answer (score 0):

> The following resources have identical contents, but are served from different URLs.

Even more important: The URLs use different protocols.

> Serve these resources from a consistent URL to save 1 request(s) and 25.2KiB.

I don’t see any saving potential here, *because* of the different protocols.

You have to “serve” the data over the appropriate protocol, depending on whether your app is called using http:// or https://

In a context, where the user’s browser will only need the HTTP *or* the HTTPS version, there is no possible “saving” at all.

In a context though, where he will need to access this content over both protocolls, there is no saving either – because the different protocols also mean they are *different* URLs, no matter if everything *after* the protocol is the same.

`http://example.com/foo` is a different resource than `https://example.com/foo` – the browser **can not** go and just fetch one out of his cache and say, *“that’ll do”*, if the other one is actually requested.

Comment: lol  getting more confusing it like opening a can of worms my skill level   need more working on ...